# Convert character "pi" to value pi

Tags: r, pi

I am working on a homework that requires two input variables and calculate the value.

```
input.c.x <-as.numeric(readline("input a variable x: "))
input.c.a<- as.numeric(readline("input a variable a: "))
output <- sin((input.c.a)*(input.c.x))
```

for variable `a`, I need to input something like "pi/180". But it will not work as a will be character and it will not converted to numbers like 3.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `readline` returns output of type "character". We can use `eval/parse` to convert data

```
input.c.x <- readline("input a variable x: ")
input.c.a <- readline("input a variable a: ")
x <- eval(parse(text = input.c.x))
y <- eval(parse(text = input.c.a))
```

and then these numbers can be used for further calculation.

```
input.c.x <- readline("input a variable x: ")
#input a variable x: pi/180

x <- eval(parse(text = input.c.x))
x
#[1] 0.01745329
```